# Laravel 10 Controller : get id in Controller by name

Tags: php, laravel, controller, laravel-10

What should I do when I want to get an id like `6` without `id` on `[{ "id": 6 }]`?

if I do:

```
public function index(string $name)
{
    $category_id = Category::where('name', $name)->get('id');

    return Inertia::render('Category', [
        'category_id' => $category_id,
        'category' => $name,
        'product' => Product::where('category', $category_id)->get()
    ]);
}
```

the `$page.props.category_id` result is

```json
[
    {
        "id": 6
    }
]
```

And `$page.props.product` result is:

```json
[]
```

And if I run `$category_id = Category::where('name', $name)->get();`, the result is:

```json
[
    {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "Arts & Crafts"
    }
]
```

And nothing changes for `$page.props.product`.

Comment: You don't need `.props.` I think. You could just do `$category_id->id` instead..?

Comment: you can try `$category_id = Category::where('name', $name)->first()->id;` or `$category_ids = Category::where('name', $name)->pluck('id');`

Comment: Thankyou guyss its solved :') Big Thanks to @FarhanIbnWahid

Comment: now i know its called pluck

Comment: @Agerr Thank you and I suggest you to go through laracasts.com tutorials for learning the Basics and Advanced features